# $ax^3+8x^2+bx+6$ is exactly divisible by $x^2-2x-3$, find the values of $a$ and $b$

Tags: polynomials

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the polynomial $ax^3+8x^2+bx+6$ is divisible by $x^2-2x-3$.

Answer (score 2):

by using the long division we get
$$\frac{ax^3+8x^2+bx+6}{x^2-2x-3}=ax+(8+2a)+\frac{(7a+b+16)x+6a+30}{x^2-2x-3}$$
now the reminder should be zero
$$7a+b+16=0\tag 1$$
$$6a+30=0\tag2$$
$$a=-5, b=19$$

Answer (score 1):

What are the roots of $x^2-2x-3$? They should also be roots in the 3rd degree polynomial.

Comment: I'm not sure, the question is word for word of what is in the title

Comment: I'm giving you a hint. You should be able to find the roots of $x^2-2x-3$ yourself. It's a quadratic equation.

Comment: (x+1)(x-3) but I don't know what to do next

Comment: So what are the roots?

Comment: x=-1, x=3, I'm sorry we just started to learn polynomials so I'm struggling

Comment: No prob. If $P(x)=ax^3+8x^2+bx+6$ is divisible by $x^2-2x-3$, it means that the two roots $x=-1$ og $x=3$ are also roots in $P(x)$. And if $x=-1$ is a root then $P(-1)=0$. Can you finish the calculations?

Comment: I got up to a + b -14 = 0

Comment: Ok then use that $P(3)=0$ you should get a second equation for $a$ and $b$. Solve them together as a linear system.

Comment: So I got P(3)= a(3)^3 + 8(3)^2 + b(3) + 6 , so a(27) + 72 + b(3) + 6, but I dont know what to do from here

Comment: You have two equations $a+b-14=0$ and $27a+3b+78=0$. This is a typical example of a linear system. You can for instance use the first equation to obtain $a=14-b$, plug it in the second equation and solve for $b$.

Comment: So I got a= 5, b=19?

Comment: You should get $a=14-b=14-19=-5$, otherwise this is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $$ax^3+8x^2+bx+6=(x^2-2x-3)(ax-2).$$ And 
$$(x^2-2x-3)(ax-2)=ax^3-(2a+2)x^2+(4-3a)x+6.$$

So clearly $a=-5, b=19$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=ax^3+8x^2+bx+6$, and let $g(x)=x^2-2x-3$. Since the question says that $g(x)|f(x)$, then write $f(x)=g(x)(px+q)$. Note the linear polynomial, we did that because dividing $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ will result in degree $1$. Now, expand the LHS and RHS, and you get something like this:
$$ax^3+8x^2+bx+6=(x^2-2x-3)(px+q)=px^3+x^2(q-2p)-x(2q+3p)-3q$$
Clearly, $q=-2,$ and $p=-5$. Now get the values of $a$ and $b$ by comparing the co-efficients.

Answer (score 1):

$$ x^2 - 2 x + 3 = ( x + 1) ( x -3) $$

$ x= -1, x = 3 $ should satisfy the polynomial. So,

$$ -a + 8 -b + 6 =0 ;\,  a \,3^3 + 8 \,3^2 - 3 \,3 + 6 =0 ;$$

Siimplify and solve for $a,b. $

Answer (score 0):

if we divide both polynomials we get
$$xa+2\,a+8+1/4\,{\frac {27\,a+3\,b+78}{x-3}}+1/4\,{\frac {a+b-14}{x+1}}$$
and the remainder must be zero. And it must be
$$27a+3b+78=0$$ and $$a+b-14=0$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint: it's not the only way to do this, but it should be helpful.
Divide the first polynomial by the second, and you'll get a remainder as a first-degree polynomial $p(x)$ , with coefficients $f(a, b)$ and $g(a, b)$. Then, since you want the first polynomial to be divisible by the second, you want the remainder to be zero, so solve the system of equations $f(a, b)=0, \space g(a, b)=0$.

Comment: yes it is the same answer as mine

Answer (score 0):

$$ax^3+8x^2+bx+6=(ax+c) (x^2-2x-3)=ax^3+(c-2a)x^2+(-2c-3a)x-3c$$
$$\begin{align}6&=-3c\Rightarrow c=-2\\8&=c-2a\Rightarrow 2a=c-8=-10\Rightarrow \color{red}{a=-5}\\b&=-2c-3a=4+15=\color{red}{19}\end{align}$$

Using this approach, you will also find out the third root is given by $ax+c=0\Rightarrow x=-\frac{2}{5}$

Also $x^2-2x-3x=(x-3)(x+1)$ gives $x=3$ and $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: roots of one of them are roots of the other. This will give you a couple of equations which you can solve.